# '-1.4210854715202E-14' is not a valid value for property 'Height'

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting this error and I do not know why:

> '-1.4210854715202E-14' is not a valid value for property 'Height'

It pops out as a message box. After I click ok, the message box is gone. When I step in, track it back in the source code where it happens, there is no error, and the message box did not show up at all.

This really bothers me: where does the problem occur and how can I trace it?

Some source code:

```
   public ICommand SetZScanStartCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._setZScanStartCommand == null)
                    this._setZScanStartCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SetZScanStart());

                return this._setZScanStartCommand;
            }
        }
```

Then:

```
  private void SetZScanStart()
        {
            _zScanStart = this._liveImage.ZPosition;
            _zRangeMin = this._liveImage.ZPosition;
            OnPropertyChanged("ZRangeMin");
            OnPropertyChanged("ZScanStart");
            OnPropertyChanged("ZScanNumSteps");
            OnPropertyChanged("ZScanThickness");
        }
```

The SetZScanStartCommand() response to a button click that pass the value of a edit box. One The edit box gives the start point, and there is another edit box similarly gives the end point. The difference between start point and end point gives the length. We are computing the number of steps, which is defined as the length divided by step size;
In our case, which crashes, start point is 6.6, end point is 1.0, step size of 0.5, so the number of the steps should be (6.6 - 1.0) / 0.5 = 11; Note it is rounded.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It might be because it is a negative value. You should check your `Height` property of your XAML.

Comment: Also it is a scientific notation. Xaml parser may could not handle it.

Comment: hint: hit break all threads when the message box is up, then you can see the stacktrace.

Comment: @vidstige: I am using vs2008, so where can I find this "break all threads"? Thanks.

Comment: @Bob.I know. But I don't my event changed any one's Height property. Besides, there are many Heights in my program, so how do I find which one is the culprit if there is any?

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Sure, I am going to edit the original thread.

Comment: 1. How many monitors are you using? and 2. Do you switch the resolution of your monitors(s) during development? Just checking... :)

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: I have 2 monitors, they are both on, but I think I am only using one of them. I don't think I switched the resolution tho.Anything else could affect this?

Comment: are the variables holding the values `6.6`, `1.0` and `0.5` of the same type?

Comment: The value is very close to -2**(-46), and is likely stored as *exactly* that value. That might help track down the problem.

Comment: Clamp the value for a valid range. That is is so close to zero, I personally not care in the least (not on UI).

Comment: @KeithThompson: The nominator is off by 1, then it gives `1/70368744177664` (too lazy to check the denominator ;p) (edit: using double precision to convert to fraction) (edit2: confirmed, denominator above is 2^46, it is not stored as that however, real fractional value is `-4503599627370495/316912650057057350374175801344`)

Comment: @KeithThompson: For interest sake, how did you get to that estimation?

Comment: @leppie: I computed `log2(1.4210854715202e-14)` (with a calculator program I have) and got `-46`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is related to a subtraction of some `float` variables in your code.

I would look first at your `float` variables, maybe replace them with another non-floating-point type, and see what happens.

Comment: I removed the inadequate link.